# How to create Build log file in Greenhills compiler?

Tags: testing, embedded, greenhills

I'm using TESSY tool for unit testing for one of my Embedded project.
and I'm using IDE CATCH in which Greenhills  is the compiler.
I need a build log file from IDE for creating a structure of the project in TESSY. Though the log file is created it is not containing compiler and linker calls with absolute path names and all used flags.
Please suggest any solutions or is there any other ways to generate a log file?

software used:

tessy ::  3.1.9

IDE :: catch (continental automotive tool chain) with CESSAR-CT

Compiler:: Green Hills MPC Green Hills multi 2000 (Default).

Comment: Is Greenhills' support offline?

Answer (score 1):

Green Hills uses a command-line switch `-commands` (or for even more detail, `-nested_commands`) to report all of the commands that it issues to its tools. You need to tell `catch` to add either of these two options to the MULTI command-line.